# Spring Boot pass down JWT from UI API to CRUD API

Tags: spring, jwt

From my first (UI) API I want to pass down the JWT to my second (CRUD) API. I don't want to do it via Parameters to the second API since it should be accessible directly as well (not just via the UI API)

```
@GetMapping("/something")
public Flux<data> firstAPICallingSecondAPI
        @AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt jwtToken) {

    return secondApi.mySecondAPI());
}
```

This works perfectly fine, and I have the JWT-data that I need. Now I need to pass this down to the second API

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/something2")
    public ResponseEntity<List<data>> mySecondAPI(
            @AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt jwtToken) {
    
    // do something with the jwtToken
    
    Service.doSomething();
  }
```

Unfortunately the jwtToken is now null in mySecondAPI, and is not passed down successfully. How can I accomplish this?